# console.error : "fontFamily "Material Icons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons, vector-icons

I'm trying to add an icon from react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

<View style={styles.picture}>
  { <Icon
    name="add-circle"
    onPress={() => alert("Add Picture")}
    color="green"
  /> }
</View>
```

but i'm getting:

> console.error : "fontFamily "Material Icons" is not a system font and
>   has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

I tried using Font.loadAsync

```
await Font.loadAsync({'MaterialIcons': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf')})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this an Expo App?

Comment: Yes, it’s expo app I’m running from vs code

Comment: `react-native-vector-icons` is included with Expo. Why are you importing it like that? You shouldn’t need to do that you should be able to access them from `@expo/vector-icons` without having to add anything else to your `package.json` https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/

Comment: That indeed works, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Expo you would be better using the Icons that are built into it.

Expo in fact comes with `react-native-vector-icons`. So you don’t need to install anything. You can just import the icons from `@expo/vector-icons`

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/

```
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

<MaterialIcons
  name="add-circle"
  onPress={() => alert("Add Picture")}
  color="green"
/>
```

It is also worth checking that the icon exists, you can do this in the [directory](https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/).